# Visual Studio Code on El Capitan doesn't start

Tags: macos, mono, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, osx-elcapitan

I downloaded VS Code from official site but can't start the app.

I tried open from console with;

```
open -a Visual Studio Code.app
```

It gives this error;

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Users/orhanveli/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app with error -10810.
```

Here is the releated error screenshot.

[image: vs code start error]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know is works well on a El Capitan fresh or upgraded install as I am using it that way.

Have you tried double-clicking the app Icon?

- If so what happens?

Try running the 'Electron' shell directly from the cli (VSC is based on Github's editor: Atom)

- Open the `Console.app`, and `Clear Display`

Then from the shell:

> $Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron

- What errors are shown in the CLI?
- What errors are shown in Console?

Comment: Yes first of all i tried dbclicking buut it gives me this error, I tried your suggestion and it terminal said that: dyld: Library not loaded: `@rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/./Electron
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/username/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework: file too short
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Answer (score 1):

I found that these steps resolve the issue:

1. In Finder, right click on Visual Studio Code.app > Show Package Contents
2. In MacOS folder, double click on Electron unix exec file

The Code should launch now within a Terminal.app process.

1. Quit Code
2. Launch Code directly from Finder
3. Accept any security pop-up

The issue should be resolved.